# Using show without alert,prompt or confirm

Tags: bootbox

Is it required to use `bootbox.alert("message",function(){example.show("another message")};`or bootbox.prompt/confirm to use show? Also is there a way to change the position of where show displays? By default it displays close to the bottom right.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm correct, show is just to get the Example object to show itself ([jquery show](http://api.jquery.com/show/) ). If that is the case, no you do not need to use the bootbox methods to use show as it is a method found in jquery. As to whether the position the Example object is displayed, it is definitely possible. I'm not sure but one way could be to write custom css. When I check the style for the 'show', this is what came up:

```
.bb-alert {
position: fixed;
bottom: 25%;
right: 0;
margin-bottom: 0;
font-size: 1.2em;
padding: 1em 1.3em;
z-index: 2000;
}
```

You could change the position of the Example object by changing the 'bottom' or the 'right' elements in the css.